# Exclude disable user Get-aduser

Tags: powershell

I want to exclude disabled user from this script but can't seem to find how i try the -exclude with no luck.

if you have a better way to do it in open to suggestion too

```
import-module ActiveDirectory;

$maxPasswordAgeTimeSpan = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge

Get-ADUser -filter * -properties PasswordLastSet, PasswordExpired, PasswordNeverExpires, EmailAddress, GivenName | foreach {

   $today=get-date
   $UserName=$_.GivenName
   $Email=$_.EmailAddress

   if (!$_.PasswordExpired -and !$_.PasswordNeverExpires) {

       $ExpiryDate=$_.PasswordLastSet + $maxPasswordAgeTimeSpan
       $DaysLeft=($ExpiryDate-$today).days

       if ($DaysLeft -lt 10 -and $DaysLeft -gt 0){

        $WarnMsg = "
<p style='font-family:arial'>Bonjour $UserName,</p>
<p style='font-family:arial'>Votre mot de passe va expirer dans $DaysLeft jours, S.V.P. changer votre mot de passe.</p>
<p style='font-family:arial'>Merci.</p>"

$enc  = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding
ForEach ($email in $_.EmailAddress) { 
send-mailmessage -to test@test -from noreply@test.com -Subject "Votre mot de passe va expirer dans $DaysLeft jours" -body $WarnMsg  -smtpserver x.x.x.x -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $enc }

    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change your filter at **Get-AdUser** from `*` to `'enabled -eq "true"'`

```
Get-ADUser -filter 'enabled -eq "true"' -properties ...
```

Comment: This performs much better.  We should avoid `-Filter *` wherever possible, since this dumps the whole AD every time.  And since `enabled` is one of his criteria...